# How can I measure the time of each video chat for accounting in connectycube?

Tags: accounting, videochat, connectycube

I need to measure the duration of the peer to peer video chats in connectycube for billing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Since ConnectyCube offers P2P calls then the only one way is to measure it on a client side, then post the data for a backend then for a billing purposes.

For example, you could setup an own timer, locally in app.
Once a call is finished - you measure a time spent on a call, then post the data to a backend, e.g. 'Custom' module. You can define a class structure in admin panel https://admin.connectycube.com/ , e.g. class with a name of 'CallsBilling' and fields like 'duration' etc. The API is available in SDKs. So the data will be store on a backend.

Then, you have all the data stored re duration, so you can apply your billing rules and process it accordingly, e.g. to ask an end user to buy an advanced plan or so